# Low voltage power transmission

Tags: electrical

i want to transmit 9v dc power overhead in 500 meter range. please tell me most suitable method for it. 
i didn't tried it but i am making this system for operating 9 Volt router of wifi device.

Comment: Don’t shout at us...

Answer (score 1):

1. Measure the current required.
2. Determine the minimum voltage (with safety margin) required to power the device correctly.
3. Measure the output of your power supply.
4. From 2 and 3 calculate the maximum voltage drop allowed.
5. From 1 and 4 calculate the maximum cable resistance allowed.
6. From 5 work out the wire size required. You can do this from cable tables or using an online calculator. Remember to check that you've included the return wire.

You may find that you require heavy, expensive cable. It may help you understand why power is transmitted at high voltage so that current can be reduced.

---

Please don't use block capitals in your question titles. It will get you some extra attention, but usually not the sort you want.